# Error handling conditions

Tags: excel, vba

The line below stops running the code if there are no empty cells in D row

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D250").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

how can I modify the code to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D250").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error Goto 0
```